# Слово "отнюдь"

Tags: этимология

А вот меня интересует слово "отнюдь". Это отрицание, но откуда оно взялось? Ну, в смысле, какая у него этимология?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каком смысле "отрицание"? Грамматически оно таковым не является, а выступает в роли усилительной частицы со значением "вовсе, совсем, никоим образом", обычно перед "нет", "не" или "без". Правда иногда встречается в самостоятельном употреблении, но это не более чем сокращение от "отнюдь нет".

Этимология
Происходит от др.-русск. от(ъ)инудь, от(ъ)инуду, русск.-церк.-слав. отинѫдь (Остром.) «отовсюду, полностью, вообще, очень, особенно» (первонач. «совсем, со всех сторон»), ст.-слав. отънѫдь (др.-греч. εἰς τὸ παντελές, ὅλως). Из оtъ и inъ, *jьnǫdu (см. ино́й). Менее убедительно сближение с* nuditi (*nǫditi), которое не объясняет мягкости -н- в русск. и др.-русск. формах на -ин-. Ср. также церк.-слав. отънѫдь(нъ) «qui аb illа раrtе est».
Викисловарь

Answer (score 0):

Отнюдь - слово прозрачное со всех сторон. Фасмер в своей статье навел невероятную тень на плетень :

> **ОТНЮДЬ** 
>    нареч., первонач. "совсем, со всех сторон", др.-русск. от(ъ)инудь, от(ъ)инуду, русск.-цслав. отиндь (Остром.) "отовсюду, полностью, вообще, очень, особенно" (Срезн. II 788), ст.-слав. отъндь (Зогр., Мар., Ассем.), (Зогр., Мар.). Из оtъ и inъ, *jьnodu (см. иной); ср. Мейе, Et. 158 и сл. **Менее убедительно сближение с *nuditi** (*noditi) (Мi. ЕW 217; Ван-Вейк, IF 30, 386; Лескин, Abulg. Gr. 159), которое не объясняет мягкости -н- в русск. и др.-русск. формах на -ин-; см. против Мейе, IF Anz. 21, 85; Преобр. I, 616, 669. Ср. также цслав. отъндь(нъ) "qui аb illа раrtе est" (МiLP 538).

Первая часть статьи Фасмера вообще отдает фантасмагорией : с чего бы **отнюдь** должно иметь связь с **отиндь**?? В русском языке мало корней???

Слово имело четыре варианта написания : отнудь, отнудъ, отнюдь, отнюдъ. В источнике 17 века смысл его объясняется проще простого : **отнюдъ отрицание всякого дела**. Естественно связать это слово с глаголом *нудити* - понуждать, увещевать, убеждать. Есть также глаголы с почти тем же самым значением, *нюкати* и *нюкнути*, от которых произошел современный глагол **понукать**.
Кого-то *нудят*, подталкивают, а он им в ответ : "Отнюдь, не хощу вашево делати!"

"Володимеръ же слушаше ихъ, бе бо сам любя жены и блуженье многое, послушаше сладко; но се ему бе нелюбо : обрезанье удовъ и о неяденьи мясъ свиныхъ, **а о питьи отнудь!**"

Использованы данные СлРЯ 11-17 вв.

"Ну давай, давай!" - "**Да не нукай**, не запряг еще..."

Дополнение.
Посмотрел словарь Миклошича, там приводятся формы *отинюдъ, отиноудь*, которые приравниваются к стандартной *отънюдъ*. Также есть раздельное написание **отъ нюдъ**, приводящее, по мнению автора словаря, к глаголу *нюдити*.
Перевод на украинский : *аж нiяк*, на современный разговорный : *не надо ля-ля*)))
Наречие *нюдьма/нюдьми* (насильно) содержит тот же корень НЮДЬ, что и наречие *отнюдь*.

Comment: Мне все-таки ближе и понятнее версия Фасмера, чем Дерзкого, в каковую я вообще до конца не въехал. Что вообще господин Дерзкий проповедует в качестве основы? "Нудити" или "Нюдь"? Все что могу сказать, Фасмер не отрицает происхождение от нудити, только ставит под сомнение возможность перехода Н в НЬ перед У. Дерзкий тем более не объясняет эту мягкость.

Comment: >Все что могу сказать, Фасмер не отрицает
происхождение от нудити, только ставит под
сомнение возможность перехода Н в НЬ перед
У. Дерзкий тем более не объясняет эту
мягкость.  

Макс Фасмер, посмотри в Старославянском словаре формы написания слова *нудити* :  
**ноудити** и **н¥дити**. Потом посмотри формы написания слова *отнюдь* :  
**отъноудь, отън¥дъ (ч/з юс большой), отън&дъ (ч/з юс малый), отнюдъ, отн¥ждъ**. Объясни, Макс Фасмер, современным  филологам, с какого такого хрена Н перешло в НЬ. И пиши, пиши новый словарь!))) 
Объясни в нем также переход **ноудьма** в **н¥дьма*, плиз...

Comment: Фасмер, ты сам-то как объясняешь происхождение наречия *отнюдь* (никоим образом) от наречия *отинуду* (отовсюду)? Каким образом смысл, написание и произношение изменились таким чудесным образом???  
>... того ради чрез сие все
идолопоклонство,   чародейство   (чернокнижество)    наикрепчайше
запрещается,  и таким образом,  что никоторое из оных **отнюдь ни в
лагере и нигде инде** не будет допущено и терпимо.  
>Воинский артикул Петра I

Comment: Шедевр от Фасмера :  
>**ТЮКАТЬ** 
тюкнуть "слегка стучать, ударять", с.-в.-р. (Барсов), "рубануть топором", арханг. (Подв.), тюкалка "молоток", укр. тюкати, блр. цюкаць "долбить". Образовано от звукоподражательного тюк (Преобр., Труды I, 29; Горяев, ЭС 382). Ср. стук, тукать, с которыми это слово **отнюдь не должно быть связано** историческими связями, вопреки Шефтеловицу (KZ 54, 233).

Comment: Что-то Грумантом запахло...  
Переход Юса Великого в У - нормально. Ю - это йотованный Ук. 
Остальное - вне моего понимания. Думаю, что сам Дерзкий тоже не очень понимает, что он хотел сказать.

Comment: Повторяю вопрос Фасмеру и его почитателям : каким образом написание *отън¥дъ, отъноудь* перешло в написание *отънюдъ, отънюдь*, далее в *отнюдъ*, *отнюдь*? В чем причина смягчения -н-... Почему глаголы *н¥дити, ноудити* совпадают своими корнями с вышеуказанными наречиями. Если же любители Фасмера = любители пошлой филодемагогии стопкран и бегемотус не могут вякнуть ничего по делу, то пусть заткнУтся (через большое У )))))))