# Каковы исторические морфемы в слове "отнюдь"?

Tags: этимология, историческое-словообразование

В  языке до сих пор существует и неплохо себя чувствует **это немного загадочное слово "отнюдь".**

1) О его происхождении  точно не мог сказать Даль:

**ОТНЮДЬ**
нареч. отнюд, отнудь **(нудить?)** никак, нисколько, никоим образом, ни под каким видом, предлогом; выражает строгий зарок или запрет, за коим следует "не".

2) **Фасмер сообщил,** что слово происходит происходит от др.-русск. от(ъ)инудь, от(ъ)инуду (первонач. «совсем, со всех сторон»), ст.-слав. отънѫдь. По поводу "нудить" он сомневался.

Может быть, конечно, но **как связать** указанные значения слова со значением его морфем?

3) **Проще всех высказался Шанский**: слово образовано на базе отъ и инъ (иной). (Правда, Шанскому принято не очень доверять, он для школьников).

Однако у местоимения ***иной*** старшее значение "один". Как тогда правильно понять: от одного подальше или от иного подальше? Или как-то по-другому?

Дважды уже задавался этот вопрос на форуме,  и обсуждался очень эмоционально, и первый раз  был даже принят, но потом опять вызвал бурную дискуссию.

[Слово "отнюдь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C)

[Происождение слова "отнюдь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23839/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C)

**Так есть ли простой и понятный ответ на этот вопрос?**

Answer (score 1):

Даль, видимо, не ставил перед собой этимологических задач, а приводимое Фасмером находит подтверждение в ряде текстов, по которым можно определить значение исходного слова "**отинуд**". Например, Псковский областной словарь с историческими данными (изд. Санкт-Петербургского университета, 2013, вып. 24, с. 82) содержит статью на это слово, с ясным по смыслу (нареч. *совсем, совершенно*) примером такого текста.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=NQxADwAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA82&img=1&zoom=3&ots=3JMMV7MDGc&sig=ACfU3U01Gib7lylc3W4_q60f7Q5ssc9fLg&w=1280

> ... и город **отинуд** пуст...

Из летописи Переяславля (Суздальского?) - по книге Афанасьев А. Н. Поэтические воззрения славян на природу, 2014 (можно усмотреть такой же смысл слова):

> ... и яки гвор в ногавици створшс образ килы имуще и не стыдящеся
>   **отинуд**, аки скомраси.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=r-d3BAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA563&img=1&zoom=3&ots=ZAXqvre8CS&sig=ACfU3U0594p_HvUoZIrSDk5s7GhoHnyP6Q&w=1280

Современное употребление слова требует последующего отрицания (*отнюдь не/нет*).

Comment: Да, спасибо, смысл слова ясен, но всё-таки можно в нем выделить исторические морфемы. Шанский назвал морфемы, но Фасмер их не называет. И происхождение от  глагола нудить категорически не отрицает.

Comment: На этот счёт приводят домыслы, но уж больно фантастические: _Слово «от инуд*» (от инъуд) есть трудно поддающееся для разумения. Если только через чувашский язык: уд, т.е. «ÿть» переводится как плоть. Инъ (иное, иной, иная), т.е. иная плоть._ http://efremov-pv.ru/blogs/o-hristianstve/page-7

Comment: Да, я думаю,что это действительно домыслы. Я такую литературу стараюсь не читать.